# sql to maintain the history of transactional table

Tags: sql, sql-server, history

I want to write sql to maintain the history of these transaction as to capture the start status and end status that are colored so can be inserted in other table

[image: tables]

the above image shows a self join of the same table suing row_number as `a.rn+1 = b.rn`

Comment: What have you tried?  What's not working?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than building this yourself, my advise is turn on [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx) for the table. Now Sql Server will keep track of this for you.

Note that this feature currently requires Enterprise Edition, but starting with 2016 sp1 it will be [included in Standard Edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx).

Comment: This can be done from the beginning, but the issue I have to do it with command now, do you know how can I handle it

Comment: If you haven't saved the data from the beginning, then the data isn't there, and there won't be anything you can do about it.